# Get flickr photoset id from photo id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, flickr

Hey, i have now used my whole day on finding out how to get other photo's in the same set as the photo is in. I do know the Photo ID but i can't find an method to find the photosets it apears in..

I'm using Rails 3, with a gem called "Flickraw"

i don't get it as a output for the getInfo on photos.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flickr.photos.getAllContexts](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getAllContexts.html)